# jQuery Load MySQL Fetch Array

Tags: mysql, ajax

I'm a beginner in jQuery area and I have simple question like this :

I want to load (AJAX) MySQL result in array, let's say :

```
$row[0] = first name
$row[1] = last name
$row[2] = phone number
```

I have no problem with PHP part, but I have difficulties to display each of that array content on different  id. because syntax I found loads everything processed by PHP :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mysql-result').load('ajax.php');
});
</script>
```

how to get 'First Name', 'Last Name' and 'Phone Number' from PHP with only one time load and still I can put the result in different . thank you.

**UPDATE**

I give you real example about what I need. Here's my HTML file named ajax.html :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Ajax Trial</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id = "fistname"><!-- ajax result goes here --></div> 
<div id = "lastname"><!-- ajax result goes here --></div>
<div id = "phonenumber"><!-- ajax result goes here --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my PHP file, named ajax.php :

```
<?php
require_once 'config-min.php';
$con = mysql_connect($DbServer,$DbUser,$DbPassword);
mysql_select_db($DbName, $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber FROM User WHERE ID = '201' LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

now, my question still same... how to get this PHP result (3 echos), load once, then displayed in those 3 different divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too wanted to do something like you wish to.And I did the following code and It worked. Hope this helps you too.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#form_plat").submit(function(e){

    var str = $(this).serialize();
    row[0]=$('#First_name').val();
    row[1]=$('#last_name').val();
    row[2]=$('#phonenumber').val();

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : 'Insert_Into.pl', //if you wish to store in database
            data : {'firstname_name':row[0],'last_name': row[1],'phonenumber':row[2]},
            beforeSend: function() {

                console.log("hey i am here");                   
            },
            success: function(){
                     $('#note').html('Thank you for your submission!');
                     $('#note').hide();                     
                     $("#fields").fadeOut('slow');
            }
         });

    return false;

  });

 });

 </script>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding to your php code:

echo $firstname.' '.$lastname.' '.$phonenumber;

Comment: I have. what I want is this echo $firstname; to be displayed on #firstname. if I'm using that script, all those echos will be displayed in #mysql-result.

Comment: I think using json is what you need. Take a look at this page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/